# asp.net mvc 4 calling method from controller by button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, asp.net-mvc-4, controllers

In my Controllers i have class AccountController and within in i have this method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

In my Views i have cshtml page with body and this part of code

```
<form class="float_left" action="Controllers/AccountController" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" title="Log out" type="submit">Log   Off</button>
</form>
```

And this doesn't work, anyone know what is problem or some other simple solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not referencing the action method here:

```
action="Controllers/AccountController"
```

For starters, you don't need to specify `Controllers/` because the framework will find the controller for you.  Indeed, the notion of a "folder" of controllers isn't known to the client/URL/etc.  What you need to give it is a "route" to the specific action method.

Since the MVC framework knows where the controllers are, you need only tell it which controller and which action method on that controller:

```
action="Account/LogOff"
```

Answer (score 5):

The `action` attribute is pointing to a wrong controller action. Your controller action is called `LogOff` and not `AccountController`. You should never be manually building `<form>` elements like that but always use the html helpers that are designed for this purpose:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account"))
{
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" title="Log out" type="submit">Log Off</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form action should probably be `/Account/LogOff`

```
< form class="float_left" action="/Account/Logoff" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" title="Log out" type="submit">Log Off</button>
</form>
```

Try putting this in the `.cshtml` file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account"))
{
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" title="Log out" type="submit">Log Off</button>
}
```